# I'm using Python to load data points using genfromtxt command but getting error message "data.txt not found"

Tags: python-2.7, genfromtxt

I've saved a .txt file of data points onto my desktop.  I wrote my script in spyder as follows:

```
from pylab import *
data = genfromtxt('data.txt', skip_header = 5, skip_footer = 6)
print data
```

This returns an error code saying "data.txt not found"
I've spent over 30 min trying to figure this out and I'm sure it's going to be a trivial fix.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is data.txt in the same directory as your script for a relative search? Or maybe typing the absolute path would work instead of just data.txt, like `r'C:\users\<username>\desktop\data.txt'`.

Comment: That worked!  I had the txt in my desktop and the py file in a separate folder.  I assumed the computer would just grab it from any directory.  Thank you.

Comment: Cool. I'll turn it into an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

With a "file not found" type of error, the error is likely based on a failed directory search, not with any specific modules like pylab. In your case, you can just add  `data.txt` to the same directory as your script. This makes a relative search work. You can also specify the absolute path, like `r'C:\users\<username>\desktop\data.txt'`. Python does other things in a directory search, like looking at your `PATH` environment variable in Windows, but working with the relative and absolute paths are the easiest.